# Basic forward list using unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, c++14, move, unique-ptr

As an exercise in learning C++, I want to build my own forward list using raw pointers and using unique_ptrs. Using raw pointers, I have:

```
struct node_raw {
    node_raw(int data_, node_raw *next_) : data(data_), next(next_) {}
    int data;
    node_raw *next;
};
```

Then I can write this

```
int main() {
    node_raw r1{1, nullptr};
    node_raw r2{2, &r1};
    node_raw r3{3, &r2};
}
```

to get a forward list: r3 -> r2 -> r1.

Now I want to do the same using unique_ptrs.

```
struct node_unique {
    node_unique(int data_, std::unique_ptr<node_unique> next_) 
        : data(data_), next(std::move(next_)) {}
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<node_unique> next;
};
```

This is what I have so far for client code:

```
int main() {
    node_unique u1{1, nullptr};
    node_unique u2{2, std::make_unique<node_unique>(std::move(u1))};
    node_unique u3{3, std::make_unique<node_unique>(std::move(u2))};
}
```

This gives `u3.next->data = 2`, so it seems to work. But is it right? Why do I need `std::move` twice to make a new node? Is it now invalid to query `u1.data` because it has been moved from? Basically, what is the canonical way to implement a minimal forward list using unique_ptrs?

Comment: `node_unique u2{2, std::move(u1)};` would be sufficient.

Comment: And directly: `node_unique u3{3, std::make_unique<node_unique>(2, std::make_unique<node_unique>(1, nullptr))};`.

Comment: FYI, using smart pointers in linked lists is generally not a good idea. For one thing, the nodes will destroy themselves recursively, and a recursive destruction can lead to a stack overflow at runtime for a long list. Iterative loops are better for linked lists. Not that you can't use an iterative loop to destroy nodes with smart pointers, but it will be a little more work, and you basically end up losing the benefit of using smart pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `nodes with smart pointers, but it will be a little more work` Only marginally. But it's indeed important to not use the implicit destructor. `and you basically end up losing the benefit of using smart pointers.` Not all of the benefits.

Comment: @eerorika "*Not all of the benefits*" - pretty much, yes. The only reason to use a smart pointer is automatic destruction, but if you have to free the nodes manually anyway and can't use automatic destruction, there is really no reason to use smart pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Other benefits that aren't lost: Implicit move and assignment are correct and don't need to be re-implemented. Easier to implement copy constructor and assignment exception safely.

Comment: I'm on the side of raw pointers in data structures where it makes sense, and I think they make a lot more sense in something like a linked list. The ownership that's intended just doesn't play well; like the hoops you have to jump through to ensure a node doesn't nuke itself and take the whole list with it. This debate is also a bit moot since you should just use `std::forward_list` or `std::list` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do I need std::move twice to make a new node?

You cannot copy `node_unique` because it has implicitly deleted copy constructor because of `std::unique_ptr` member.

> Is it now invalid to query u1.data because it has been moved from?

No. The implicitly generated move constructor will copy the member. It's not invalid to read the `int` member that was copied from.

> But is it right?

There isn't a huge problem<sup>1</sup> with the node class itself, but the way that you're using it may potentially be misleading. `u1` and `u2` aren't part of the list whose root is `u3`. The list nodes are shallow copies of the moved-from `u1` and `u2`.

You don't necessarily need the variables; since the list elements will be dynamic, you can create them directly:

```
node_unique root (
    3,
    std::make_unique<node_unique>(
        2,
        std::make_unique<node_unique>(
            1,
            nullptr
        )
    )
);
```

> Basically, what is the canonical way to implement a minimal forward list using unique_ptrs?

"Minimal" is relative to what your requirements are. You could make it more minimal by removing the constructor to make the node an [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special).

I wouldn't say that there is a "canonical" way to implement a forward list, but it would be expected to meet the concept of a `Container`. That would however be less minimal.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except for the fact that destructor has linear recursion depth which will cause stack overflow with moderately sized lists as pointed out by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72030976/basic-forward-list-using-unique-ptrs/72031446#comment127277242_72030976).

You should implement a custom destructor that destroys the nodes iteratively. This requires a bit of thought to prevent the smart pointer destructors from delving into recursion.

Comment: You mean "it has an implicitly deleted copy constructor" instead of "it has an implicitly deleted move constructor" I assume?

Comment: @JakobStark Indded. Fixed.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks for the reply. I have also removed the C++11 tag and added C++14.

Comment: Is it important that it works with an 'early' version? Perhaps just remove the tag?